# How to attach the DNX process when using Postman or Fiddler?

Tags: visual-studio, fiddler, postman

I use Visual Studio 2015, a Web API project and DNX as the hosting environment. To test the APIs, I use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). I often use Fiddler also.

Here is how I debug. I look for the DNX process in the Visual Studio 2015, attach to that process, and then run the API in the post man. It is working fine. But it is tedious when I have to do this repeatedly for many APIs.

Is there a quick way where by when I run the API in the Postman, the process is automatically attached to the Visual Studio and breaks at the break point in the code?